# how to pass parameters to jquery ui callback functions

Tags: jquery

I have several jquery ui objects and they all have a similar callback:

```
$(function() {
    $("#my_list").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                },
                success: response,
                dataType: 'json',
                minLength: 0,
            });

        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
              $('something').appendTo("#another_list");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

If I could pass the "my_list" and "another_list" there as parameters, the code would be much cleaner.
How can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand in which function you want to get the "my_list" and "another_list" as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap that code in a function?

```
function initAutocomplete(list1, list2){
    $(list1).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                },
                success: response,
                dataType: 'json',
                minLength: 0,
            });

        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
              $('something').appendTo(list2);
            }

        }
    });
}

$(function(){
  initiAutocomplete('#my_list', '#another_list');
  initiAutocomplete('#my_second_list', '#another_list_part_deux');
});
```

Comment: That worked great. I just have a silly question. Am I correct that jquery-ui uses the callback signature $(function(){}); and tell it what event to trigger it on (like click event)?

Comment: `$(function(){})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready`. that it, it waits until the dom is fully loaded before executing any code within that callback. its not specific to jquery-ui